# Change values of a properties file in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, properties-file

I have a properties file in my application which has two properties (username,password). I want to change the value of these properties when I'm pressing a Button I have on my gui ! The problem is that my properties file is stored in a package of my project and not in the root folder so when I press the button an Exception of File not found is fired and the changes didn't take effect ! I tried to change the path , but the results remains the same , exception fired and no change take effect !

Part of my sourcecode of my button listener in which I trto do the changes is this :

```
try {
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("src/Settings/settings.properties");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
    input.close();

    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("src/Settings/settings.properties");
    prop.setProperty("password", "yoyo");
    prop.store(output, null);
    output.close();
}
catch(IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Question:  why are you attempting to modify values that were intended to be concrete and independent of your code?

Comment: These values are wmpty when someone starta the program for first time ! But after his login I want these values to take his username and password , that he has provided in order to login ! That's why !

Comment: So why don't you store these... *not* in a properties file?  Somewhere where the data could be mutated freely?

Comment: I want to store them in a property file ! Why not  try to learn how to do it rather than finding another way to do it ?!

Comment: It doesn't make practical sense to.  This coming from a guy that's worked in multiple properties files, all intended to be concrete and never changing.  From [the trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) it looks like there's a way to do it, but I maintain, you should probably do something *else* to store a username/password combination.  Anything else.

Comment: Could you add an example as answer as I'm newbie to java and the oracle's tutorials it's a little complicated for me . The problem is about the location of the file , if I access it some way the rest work fine !

Comment: Just put it somewhere else. The src directory won't be there at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way: Read the entire properties file in. Write out a new copy with the desired change.

That's the only way to change ANY file that doesn't have fixed record blocks.